# Elements in ring that satisfy $x^{m+n}=x^m$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I am trying to recall a statement about ring which talks about the existence of an element $x$ that has the property $x^{m+n}=x^n$ for some positive integers $m$ and $n$, but I cannot remember where I read it before and cannot find any reference talking about this, and don't even remember whether this element or the ring has a specific name or not. Perhaps anyone can give me any reference or maybe explanation about this? I really appreciate the help. Thanks!

Comment: Every element in a finite ring has this property, proven by pigeonhole principle.  In rings which are not finite, nilpotent and idempotent elements satisfy the property but are not the only examples.

Comment: You want to solve $x^n(x^m-1)=0$. $x=0$ and $x=1$ are obvious possibilities. More generally, if your ring has no zerodivisors, you look for roots of the factors, i.e.: $m$-th roots of unity; and nilpotent elements. In general rings, there will be many more.